# Array in Json with Symfony2

Tags: php, arrays, json, symfony

this is what i want:

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "targetGroup": {
        "age": [5],
        "gender": [1],
        "income": [2]
    }
    ...
    ,
    {
        ...
    }
}]
```

i want an array in my json return.

Here is my Symfony Action:

```
public function advertisingPartnersAction() {
    $serializer = SerializerBuilder::create()->build();

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('MainBundle:Promotion');
    $query = $em->createQueryBuilder('qbPromotion')
            ->select('qbPromotion.id,qbEntry.entTitle,qbIndustry.indTitle,qbPacking.packTitle,qbEntry.edition,qbEntry.tkp')
            ->join('qbPromotion.entry2', 'qbEntry')
            ->join('qbEntry.packing', 'qbPacking')
            ->join('qbEntry.industry', 'qbIndustry')
            ->getQuery();

    $entity = $query->getResult();

    if ($entity) {
        $jsonEntity = $serializer->serialize($entity, 'json');
    } else {
        // TODO error
        die;
    }

    return new JsonResponse(json_decode($jsonEntity, true));
}
```

This works fine and returns:

```
[
    {"id":2,"entTitle":"Titel","indTitle":"Food","packTitle":"Karton","edition":1,"tkp":"38.10"},
    {"id":3,"entTitle":"Titel","indTitle":"Food","packTitle":"Karton","edition":1,"tkp":"38.10"},
    {"id":1,"entTitle":"Titel 2","indTitle":"Getr\u00e4nke","packTitle":"Flasche","edition":2,"tkp":"38.20"}
]
```

But i need an array like targetGroup in my json. How can i get it work?

Comment: First of all, don't worry about how to format things in JSON. That is done for you.  Just create the data structure you want in PHP. Since you are not clear as to what "targetGroup" is or how it is derived, there is not a lot else that can be done to help you.  Second, why are you serializing, then deserializing, then re-serializing to/from JSON.  Just do it once.

Comment: I guess that targetGroup is a Doctrine entity. That's why it is serialized as an object.

Comment: targetGroup is the arrayname and the array has 3 attributes(ids) from 3 tables. I need to return a json with an array in it.